# How to associate file extension with executable using bash?

Tags: bash, file-extensions

In my bash script `setup.sh`, how to make macOS associate `.foo` extension with `/usr/local/bin/bar`, so that I can click on `X.foo` in Finder (say) and have macOS perform `/usr/local/bin/bar X.foo`?